# Is it better to wash eggs before refrigerating?

Tags: food-safety, eggs, storage-method

I want to know how to store eggs in the refrigerator. Some people say to never wash them, others say it's ok to wash eggs before refrigerating. Which is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would personally avoid washing the eggs.

The problem is that [wet eggs are bad](http://www.thepoultrysite.com/articles/1046/the-importance-of-preventing-sweating-eggs/).  This goes for both Europe, where the eggs are sold unwashed, and in the US, where the eggs are pre-washed and refrigerated.

If you did wash your eggs, you need to get them thoroughly dry afterwards.  Otherwise, you *will* do harm to the eggs.

If you're buying unwashed eggs, you could use a dry brush on them before you stored them, but I wouldn't recommend anything more than that.

Comment: Can you please explain why and how do washed eggs can harm?

Comment: @ASIM : it's in the link : "Sweating of eggs should be avoided because moisture on the shell surface weakens the egg's natural defence mechanisms, providing as it does an ideal environment for the growth of micro-organisms, and further facilitating their penetration through the shell pores. "

Answer (score 2):

I raised chickens and handled many hundreds of eggs (my all time high was over 200 in one day.) I didn't like the idea of unwashed eggs going into the refrigerator, though they appeared quite clean.

Washing eggs does make the shells a bit more porous, so washed eggs don't stay fresh quite as long. If you do wash them, though, it's important to wash them in warm to hot water so that the contents expand slightly as they are being washed. That way, no wash water (or more importantly, bacteria in the wash water) enters the egg. Cold water would cause the contents to contract a bit allowing seepage into the egg. A quick wash/rinse with plain water is fine.

There are other ways to clean an egg, but it is far more work imo.

If you don't plan to refrigerate the eggs, you might want to just let them be, wiping off any dirt. Keeping the nesting boxes clean and good management of the coop/flock is important.

Comment: Did you wash the eggs before use?

Comment: @Rob - I washed them once, after collecting. That's all. Sometimes, if I knew I would be using them that day, I would not refrigerate them, therefore did not wash them at all.

Comment: I ask because, if they come right from the coop, and then you crack them for use, the dirt and everything else gets pushed into the contents or when it runs down the side of the shell and into your pan.

Comment: @Rob - I assume you'll be cooking them immediately after? This reduces the risk considerably. I like to wash my eggs, but I know not everyone does, and not all those who don't get sick. The real risk (I think) is washing, storing, or using/handling them improperly.

Comment: @Rob - Also please note: if the eggs are lain on clean sawdust (what I used), they *appeared* pristine. I would never take a dirty egg into the house.